# Multiplying data frame by vector with if-else conditional

Tags: r

I am performing a Box-Cox transformation for a linear regression model but am having some trouble implementing this in `R`.

I have already obtained the optimal lambda values for Box-Cox. I am trying to perform the following in `R`:

```
opt.lambda.test<- lapply(temp.list, function(x) with(x, x[which.max(y)]))
```

That extracts the optimal lambda's from Box-Cox. `temp.list` is the list of regression results.

```
opt.lambda.test
[[1]]
[1] 0.77

[[2]]
[1] 3.46
```

Then I turn this into a vector:

```
vec.lambda <- unlist(opt.lambda.test)
```

I have a data frame, in this example, with 2 columns. Here is a snippet:

```
       x_1       x_2
[1,]  99.81974  99.43289
[2,] 102.20328 103.68653
....
```

Full data frame is just:

```
 x_1 <- rnorm(100,mean=100,sd=1)
 x_2 <- rnorm(100,mean=100,sd=4)
 x.temp1<-cbind(x_1,x_2)
```

In the actual data I am analyzing, the columns won't have the same number of rows.

Any-who, I want each of column of the data frame to be raised to the power of the value in `vec.lambda`. In this case, `x_1`$^{0.77}$ and `x_2`$^{3.46}$ and so on and so forth. The length of `vec.lamba` will always equal the number of columns of the data frame.

BUT, if `vec.lambda == 0` I want the column to be transformed as: $log(x_{i})$. I can't get the first part working so I was hoping for some help with the conditional aspect of this data frame manipulation and the plain old data frame manipulation.

```
x.test.1 <- apply(x.temp1,2,function(x) x^vec.lambda)
```

Is it my naive attempt that didn't work?

Comment: I've suggested this should be closed and migrated to [so] as what you want help with is not statistical but rather help with the right R incantation to get it to do what you want. I think the Q is a good one (+1) and is well illustrated. Allow the Moderators time to migrate the question if they agree; please don't cross-post to [so] yourself.

Comment: +1 @GavinSimpson No stats question here, purely R programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are applying your function to each column rather than each row. If you changed the `2` to a `1`, you'd almost have what you want; you'd actually have the transpose of what you want (because `apply` will place each result in a column), but it's easy enough to just transpose the result:

```
t(apply(x.temp1,1,function(x) x^vec.lambda))
```

However, there are other approaches that might be faster. R will recycle values along and then across columns, so you could transpose your matrix (so that a column has two rows), raise it to `vec.lambda` (this will be repeated automatically for each column), and then transpose the result:

```
t(t(x.temp1) ^ vec.lambda)
```

You could also create a vector the same length as `x.temp1` and just raise `x.temp1` to this:

```
x.temp1 ^ rep(vec.lambda, each=nrow(x.temp1))
```

Or even a matrix the same dimensions as `x.temp1`, so that `x.temp1[i, j]` should be raised to `mat.lambda[i, j]`. Perhaps this is the clearest approach:

```
mat.lambda <- matrix(vec.lambda, ncol=2, nrow=nrow(x.temp1), byrow=TRUE)
x.temp1 ^ mat.lambda
```

As for your desire to perform a different operation when `vec.lambda` is zero, one way is to use `ifelse`:

```
mat.lambda <- matrix(vec.lambda, ncol=2, nrow=nrow(x.temp1), byrow=TRUE)
ifelse(mat.lambda==0, log(x.temp1), x.temp1 ^ mat.lambda)
```

Comment: Deleted older comment on accident... Perfect! Thanks for the help.